# How to make an onclick event active on all child elements

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have a large div with multiple sub elements inside of it. I have attached an onclick event to the large div tag. However, the onclick event only works when you click on empty space inside of the large div. It does not work when you click on child elements such as text inside of the large div. I am wondering if there is an easy way to capture any clicks inside of the large div, so I do not need to attach the onclick event to every child element.

EDIT: Add code snippet

Try to change text from blue to red. When you click on the empty space of the larger div, the text changes color. When you click on the child elements(the text), the color does not change. Is there an easy fix to be able to click anywhere inside of the large div to change the text color.

```js
function changeToRed() {
event.target.querySelector('.change').style.color = "red";
}
```

```css
.change {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="changeToRed()">
<p class="change">Change text color</p>
<p> Another Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put your code so we could consider the problem.

Comment: That is because when you click on the nested elements, the `event.target` does not refer to the parent and therefore the query selector returns nothing. You should be using `event.currentTarget`, which refers to the element that the click handler is bound to.

Comment: Right. So I guess what I am wondering, is there a way for the div to be seen as "in front of the text."  So when you click on the text, it sees it as clicking on the div. I do not want to attach the onclick event to all elements if I do not need to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an overlay element on your existing element and make it transparent with css and add the eventlistener on this overlay element!